# Pentaho MongoDB Atlas connection issue

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, mongodb-atlas

I’m trying to connect Pentaho PDI (CE) to mongoDB hosted by Atlas, but getting an error, complaining about the host name I believe.

All examples on the internet is for connecting pentaho with mongodb with host = localhost; somehow when I pass the Atlas hostname it doesn’t seem to resolve.

Anyone been able to connect pentaho to a mongodb atlas cluster that could help me please?

Oh, I’m able to connect via compass and via command line.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Host name was wrong. Fixed it by adding the correct one.

Comment: Hi henrique. Could you shed some light on what the "correct host name" was ? Would be nice for those who face the same difficulty.